# ReferenceError: paypal is not defined when i setup PayPal Checkout using vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a component PaypalButton.vue and when i implement my button following these instructions: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
  </div>
</template>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AZy2xQtNMcibA3BneS56WHoq1oqLhWdM7nsP3pwS02lr_1TOpC9Lnpp-IGbZQDS8K_xvMH5ssRmNPoDT" >
      // Required. Replace SB_CLIENT_ID with your sandbox client ID.
    </script>


<script>
import JQuery from 'jquery'
let $ = JQuery

var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
   if ($('#paypal-button-container').length) {
      console.log("Exists!");
      paypal
  .Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [
          {
            amount: {
              value: "0.01"
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
        alert("Transaction completed by " + details.payer.name.given_name);
      });
    }
  })
  .render("#paypal-button-container");
//This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.

      clearInterval(checkExist);
   }
}, 100); // check every 100ms


export default {
  data: () => ({
    //
  })
};
</script>
```

I get this error..does someone know what is happening? I tried to import the paypal script in index.html but the same thing happens

[image]

Comment: Are you using an actual client-id? This is not secret information, so you can include it in your post so we can test what's wrong. If your code works when run independently, there may be something about your vue environment that is preventing the PayPal script from being loaded properly, and so we'll need a way to test it.

Comment: i updated my code. I tried to implement a function that waits for my component to load before executing my script so i can solve another error:Document is ready and element #paypal-button-container does not exist.

Comment: For the paypal undefined error, i added the script in both files..index and the playbutton component

Comment: dont know if its the right way but it works lol

Comment: Not supper familiar with vue but I think the index is where it needs to be.  I'm not sure you need the checkExist interval, though it'll certainly work.  You could try a `$(document).ready(function(...` instead if something like that is needed

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a similar problem with the "'script' is not defined" problem. So this is my solution using a script for a similar purpose. I hope it helps someone. First, I needed to use the "window" scope. Also, if you need to access any Vue element inside the "onload" function, you need a new variable for the "this" instance.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>PayWay Payment</h2>
    <div id="payway-credit-card"></div>
    <br />
    <button id="pay" disabled>Add credit card</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "Payment",
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["aVueAction"])
  },
  created() {
    let paywayScript = document.createElement("script");
    let self = this;
    paywayScript.onload = () => {
      // call to Vuex action.
      self.aVueAction();
      // call to script function
      window.payway.aScriptFunction();
    };
    // paywayScript.async = true;
    paywayScript.setAttribute(
      "src",
     "https://api.payway.com.au/rest/v1/payway.js"
    );
    document.body.appendChild(paywayScript);
  }
};
</script>
```

I worked with this on Vue 2.6.